# Ruby on Rails page load error "could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

When I run my "rails server" command, and go to my web page, I get this error http://s7.postimg.org/jcxqxl3gr/image.png I am using Postgresql and have only installed the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. I am using rails 4.0.0. Why is it showing me this error? I installed everything through railsinstaller, but update to 4.0.0 through rubygems.

Any help would be aprreciated,

Amar

EDIT:

Sorry for the late edit, but here is the current contents of my development log file:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-02 09:39:00 +1200

PG::Error (could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__790143164__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (106.1ms)
```

Comment: And what is in rails log?

Comment: Major possible reasons: postgres is not running, or rails is not pointing to it, or a firewall rejects the connection.

Comment: Just updated it then with the log files. Again sorry for the late edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that your postgres server is not running.Thats why you get this error try to run it.
you are using windows so try to check this link it will give you some hint

[postgreSQL database service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482239/postgresql-database-service)

Comment: Thanks, the link solved my problem, and I did a reinstall of postgres.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem to, I tried to run an external project and didn't even knew that this project required PostgreSQL... :)