# PostgreSQL app on windows not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a new app with psotgresql instead of sqlite3 and the command

`db:migrate`

is not working

Here is the full log with `db:migrate --trace`

```
    C:\Users\Jaiel\Desktop\Uebung_3_Elias_Kechter_s0555064_SoSe_2018_AI_Web_Entwicklung\order_management>rails db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-1.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-1.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-1.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:697:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:221:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:20:in `table_exists?'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:24:in `create_table'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1125:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I havent found any solution and im sad because it actuylla works with sqlite3 but I need to have postgresql for Heroku deployment...

Comment: add pg on production group only

Comment: Did you try installing postgresql locally? What was the result?

Comment: Do you have postgres? If not you can just download it from their website (it's free)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:
[postgreSQL database service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482239/postgresql-database-service)

As mentioned in the answer (user: ontrack) below

Use services (start -> run -> services.msc) and look for the postgresql-[version] service.

- If it is not there you might have just installed pgAdmin and not installed PostgreSQL itself.
- If it is not running try to start it, if it won't start open the event-viewer (start -> run -> eventvwr) and look for error messages relating to the PostgreSQL service.
- If it does start check the startup type, if you want it to start with windows it should be "Automatic"; or perhaps "Automatic, delayed start" if you don't want it to slow down startup too much.

---